# How to look for non-exact string match within a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main sub that goes through all the Excel files within a folder and some functions that does different things. One of the function looks for matches within a column. Here's the code for main sub:

```
Public Discipline As String

Public Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()

    Dim FolderAddress As String
    Dim MyFiles As String
    
    FolderAddress = "C:\Users\amira\Desktop\Sapura Energy\Man Hours\AsBuiltFinal"
    
'Step 2: Specify a target folder/directory, you may change it.
    MyFiles = Dir(FolderAddress & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
    
'Step 3: Open Workbooks one by one
    Workbooks.Open FolderAddress & "\" & MyFiles

    'Run some code here
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    'Determine the discipline name
    Discipline = NameDisc()
    
    'Find row number of said discipline
    Dim DiscRow As String
    
    DiscRow = RowDisc()

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Step 4: Next File in the folder/Directory
    MyFiles = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Here's the code for the function :

```
Public Function RowDisc()

Dim srchrng As Range
Dim RowOfDisc As Variant

Set srchrng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
    
    RowOfDisc = Application.Match(Discipline, srchrng)
    If IsError(RowOfDisc) Then
        MsgBox ("Discipline Not Found")
    End If

End Function
```

The problem is that in the function, `RowOfDisc` does not give me the row number of `Discipline` rather an arbitrary row. I've also checked that `Discipline` and `srchrng` is correctly defined by looking at watch.

Another thing is that I would also like to match the `Discipline` when the cell has some other things in it, say "Discipline Total", how do I go about doing that? I've tried using `Discipline & "*"` but that didn't work.

Comment: There's not much benefit to having a separate function here (particularly if you're relying on globals and Activesheet...)   If you move the match inside your loop do you get the expected answer?  Also - note your function doesn't actually return anything (somewhere you need `RowDisc = [return value here]` )

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the feedback. I've moved it over and integrated it into the main sub but it gave me row number 6 which has ": March 20" in it whereas `Discipline` is "Brown Field Structural" so I'm not really sure how it got there..

Comment: You are specifying a approximate match instead of an exact one. The "approximate" (1) is the default. You can specify "exact" with `Application.Match(Discipline, srchrng, 0)`

Comment: @TimWilliams so here's one of the problems I'm facing. Some of the disciplines won't have exact matches. It works when the cell value = `Discipline` but when the cell value is `Discipline` & "some string" it gives me an error.

Comment: I just figured it out! I added a & "*" after `Discipline` in the Match and it works.